# echo -n not inputing anything, even though echo has no parameters

Tags: command-line, echo

On the terminal, typing `echo -n`  will not output anything at all, if echo has no parameters, then why using parameter -n does nothing in echo at all? Note: Doing something like `echo nil -n nil` will work and output `nil -n nil`, so if echo outputs everything, then why doesn't it output `-n`, it should output `-n` not doing nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `echo` appends a newline character to it's output, so if you issue echo without any parameters, the output is nothing, followed by a newline.

The `-n` option means 'do not output the trailing newline'. So when you issue `echo -n` it uses the `-n` as an option, and outputs nothing without a newline. This will leave no evidence of output on the display.

If you use a letter which is not a valid option for `echo` such as '-x' it will be printed to the screen, with a newline as normal. If you use -n within other input, it is not read as an option, so will print normally.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Arronical](https://askubuntu.com/users/320386/arronical)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676579/45659), `echo` does not support `--`, which is the standard convention to declare
"This is end of options/flags, consider everything that follows as arguments."

GNU `echo` can be made to output `-n` by using

```
echo -e "\e--n"
```

In `zsh`, `echo` is a shell built in, and `echo - -n` does the job.